# Sent items are stored in own mailbox instead of shared mailbox

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, outlook-2007

E-mail sent from (not on behalf) a shared mailbox is stored in the user's mailbox sent items folder instead of the sent items folder in the shared mailbox.

There is apparantly a hotfix ([KB2181579](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2181579)) but that only works with Cached Exchange Mode enabled.

Enabling Cached Exchange Mode is PITA, as it has its own problems (missing folders, calendar items missing/not synchronizing etc)

Is there a way to store the sent items in the shared mailbox, which does not involve rules?

Comment: I'm curious on your comment "enabling cached exchange mode is a PITA" since this is the recommended (and nowadays normal) way for Outlook to operate in an Exchange environment.

Comment: It happens often that mail folders just disappear from Outlook's cached copy. And we've seen a lot of mysterious problems with shared calendars (for example: calendars that appear empty in cached mode, but do have appointments in them) and now this problem with saving sent items to the user's folders instead of the mailbox where it belongs.

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure if this would answer your query.
Create a rule on OWA (webmail) and open your shared mailbox on which the sent item has to be saved.
Open Options in the (Shared Mailbox webmail)

[image]

And go to Mail -> Automatic processing -> Inbox and sweep rules and create a rule to download the Sent Items which are saved in Personal mailbox

[[image][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCEZy.png)